# Segmentation Fault in a for loop due to struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, typedef

I had an already working program and now have to change the 4 arrays used into 1, so I used a typedef struct and created a data type called stuff. Then made an array of data type stuff called everything. Everything contains four arrays:

```
typedef struct structure
{
char names[13][9];
int scores[13][4];
float average[13];
char letter[13];
} stuff;
```

Later in the program, fopen is called like this:

```
FILE *student, *score;
student = fopen("student.dat", "r");
score = fopen("scores.dat", "r");
```

And fscanf is used a little after that:

```
for(i=0; i<13; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
    fscanf(score, "%d", everything[i].scores[i][j]);
    }
}
fclose(score);
```

I kept getting a segmentation fault after I finished the entire program and wasn't sure where it was coming from so I commented out everything and uncommented it piece by piece to see where the segmentation fault started happening. It started popping up again right here and I'm not sure why. What do I do to fix it?

Comment: Always, over and over and over... 1. You should read the documentation of `fscanf()` instead of making assumptions. 2. C has no pass-by-reference.

Comment: @H2CO3 Please explain what C not having pass-by-reference has to do with it.My knowledge about that is really fuzzy and I want to understand the gist of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistake in this line `fscanf(score, "%d", everything[i].scores[i][j]);`.

Better use this

`fscanf(score, "%d", &everything[i].scores[i][j]);`. You forget `&` in this line. You have to tell `mem address` to store scan value.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that I've been working at this for like an hour. Thank you so much I feel so stupid.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather the issue is that everything does not contain 13 instances of your struct so when it is trying to go through the for loop it can't find the relevant place in memory to store the data.